# Root test of $\sum_{x = 1} \frac{n}{3^n}$ is inconsistent with ratio test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I had the following homework question where I had to determine if the following expression converges by using the [root test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RootTest.aspx).

$$\sum_{n = 1} \frac{n}{3^n}$$

This is what I tried:

$$\begin{align}
& \sum_{n = 1} \frac{n}{3^n} = \\
& \sum_{n = 1} \left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{3} \right)^n \rightarrow \\
& \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\left( \frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{3} \right)^n} = \\
& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n}}{3} = \\
& \infty
\end{align}$$

Since the limit is greater then one, I concluded that the expression diverges.

However, I tried using the [ratio test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RatioTest.aspx) to confirm my answer, and obtained the following:

$$\begin{align}
& \sum_{n = 1} \frac{n}{3^n} \rightarrow \\
& \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{n + 1}{3^{n + 1}}}{\frac{n}{3^n}} = \\
& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n + 1}{3 \cdot 3^n} \cdot \frac{3^n}{n} = \\
& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n + 1}{3n} = \\
& \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

Since the limit is less then one, according to the ratio test, the sequence converges.

What gives? Have I misunderstood how to apply the root and ratio test, or is there an error in my math somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root test gives you $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^{1/n}}{3}$$ where $n^{1/n}\rightarrow 1$ by L.Hospital Rule. So this is definitely less than 1.